# Run with apache + mod_wsgi, Import error: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied

Tags: python, apache, flask, scipy, mod-wsgi

I'm using apache with Flask and mod_wsgi.
When I import scipy module on my Flask script I got this error.

```
[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymatgen/electronic_structure/plotter.py", line 671, in get_plot3

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]     import scipy.interpolate as scint

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 145, in <module>

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]     from .interpolate import *

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 16, in <module>

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]     import scipy.special as spec

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 608, in <module>

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]     from ._ellip_harm import ellip_harm, ellip_harm_2, ellip_normal

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ellip_harm.py", line 7, in <module>

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]     from ._ellip_harm_2 import _ellipsoid, _ellipsoid_norm

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx", line 2, in init scipy.special._ellip_harm_2 (scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.c:7444)

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error]     from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array

[Thu Oct 15 18:15:45 2015] [error] ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

How can I fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using a SELinux enabled distribution like CentOS. When your app is behind Apache using `mod_wsgi`, you have to set the label `httpd_sys_script_exec_t` to the shared object files before your app can access them.

In the following example I will assume that your application is in `/var/www/myapp` directory with Python 2.7 virtualenv in `/var/www/myapp/venv` and Numpy and Scipy is installed in that virtualenv as well.

You can add permanently the new SELinux policy using `semanage`:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t "/var/www/myapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages(/.*)?"
```

And then you can activate them with `restorecon`:

```
restorecon -R /var/www/myapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

If you install a new package in the virtualenv which has a shared object file, then you have to run the `restorecon` command again (or reboot).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work.
First of all, Numpy and Scipy is not installed in my /var/www/app/venv ..
It only installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7
So I tried `semanage` command my '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so' and '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/'
But i didn't work too..

Comment: After then I tryed `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so` and I got new error message.. 
`ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`

Comment: I fixed by `chcon -t texrel_shlib_t`
But still `ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied`

Comment: I'm sure you have to set the `httpd_sys_script_exec_t` label, the `httpd_sys_content_rw_t` is for read/write access.

Note that if your use `chcon`, you have to repeat it after a reboot. For permanent solution use the `semanage` context. Make sure to use the syntax like in my example for setting labels recursively. A simple `semanage (...) /usr/local/lib/python2.7` will not work.